# Find and get array key from multilevel array from other array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array structure, and i want to find and compare with other array that i have.

This is the array that i want search:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      'vlr' => string '60000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Blanco' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      'vlr' => string '40000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Blanco' (length=6)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Madera' (length=6)
      'vlr' => string '60000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Verde' (length=5)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Madera' (length=6)
      'vlr' => string '40000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
```

An this is the array with search values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blanco
    [1] => 32GB
    [2] => Plastico
)
```

I have the key and value, but i need find, in this example the main key is 1 in the long and main array, how can i get that?

PD: the number of search values are the numbers inside main arrays

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that `elements` is the name of the array that you want to iterate over and find the index whose first three values match the search values. You can simply iterate over the `elements`, checking if the values match and if they do, then you can store the index in a variable called `$wantedKey`:

```
$target = array(
    '0' => Blanco
    '1' => 32GB
    '2' => Plastico
);

$wantedKey = null;

foreach($elements as $key => $elem){
  if($elem[0] == $target[0] && $elem[1] == $target[1] && $elem[2] == $target[2]){
      $wantedKey = $key;
      break;
   }
}

echo $wantedKey;
```

In case you have an arbitrary amount of values, you can use a `foreach` to iterate over them and check if they match:

```
foreach($elements as $key => $elem){
    $sameValues = true;
    foreach($target as $t_key => $t_value){
        if($elem[$t_key] != $t_value){
            $sameValues = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($sameValues){
        $wantedKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}

echo $wantedKey;
```

Comment: Yes i have the principal key with this code, but i have one last problem, if the $target array have multiple values, not 3 like in the example, for example:

```
$target = array(
    '0' => Blanco
    '1' => 32GB
    '2' => Plastico
    '3' => 'Other'
);
```
Its for multiple select items and search that in array principal

Comment: @Rocket Updated my answer.